How to animate a radar chart
So I am very new to coding, but a friend asked me to help them make a radar chart that showcases their skills. I have found an example online that I have made some changes to to customize it to their needs. The issue I am having is figuring out how to animate it. What I am trying to do is have each of the plot points move out one at a time until the chart is fully expanded. I then am trying to have each of them collapse from their final value (ie. 65) back to 0, and then repeat the process of expanding again. So basically I want them to expand out one at a time and then after they are all expanded to collapse one by one until the are back to zero, then out again and have this continuously repeat (if possible). I am not sure if this is possible or too much. I have looked online for any sort of animation to at least expand one by one, but I can't find anything. I am including the code I have below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Radar Chart in JavaScript</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-radar.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>

      anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

        // create a data set
        var chartData = {
          rows: [
            ['Advertising', 33],
            ['Branding', 34],
            ['Creative Problem-Solving', 17],
            ['Digital Marketing', 50],
            ['Research', 24],
            ['SEO', 11],
            ['Social Media Marketing', 59],
            ['Strategy', 43],
            ['UI', 22],
            ['UX', 73]
          ]
        };

        // create a radar chart
        var chart = anychart.radar();

        // set the series type
        chart.defaultSeriesType('area');

        // set the chart data
        chart.data(chartData);

        // set the color palette
        chart.palette(['#9BC53DE6']);

        // configure the appearance of the y-axis
        chart.yAxis().stroke('#000000');
        chart.yAxis().ticks().stroke('#000000');

        // configure the stroke of the x-grid
        chart.xGrid().stroke({
          color: "#545f69",
          thickness: 0.5,
          dash: "10 5"
        });

        // configure the appearance of the y-grid
        chart.yGrid().palette(['gray 0.05', 'gray 0.025']);

        // begin the y-scale at 0
        chart.yScale().minimum(0);

        // set the y-scale ticks interval
        chart.yScale().ticks().interval(10);

        // set the hover mode
        chart.interactivity().hoverMode('by-x');

        //  set the marker type
        chart.markerPalette(['star5']);

        // improve the tooltip
        chart.tooltip()
          .displayMode('union')
          .useHtml(true)
          .format(function(e){
            console.log(this);
            return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color() + '">' +
              this.seriesName + ": " + this.value + "</span>"
          });

        // set chart legend settings
        chart.legend()
          .align('center')
          .position('center-bottom')
          .enabled(false);

        // set the chart title
        chart.title("Services");

        // set container id for the chart
        chart.container('container');

        // initiate chart drawing
        chart.draw();
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>

If possible could you please provide me with help on how to code something like this. I will need to include it in this code as they need one html file that they can upload to their Wix website.
I am not sure if any of this is possible, but I would really appreciate any sort of help or code that I can use.
Thank you so much for your time and help.

I gave it a go, is this what you are looking for? Note that the speed and step variables are adjustable.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Radar Chart Animation</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-radar.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>

      anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

        var originalData = {
          rows: [
            ['Advertising', 33],
            ['Branding', 34],
            ['Creative Problem-Solving', 17],
            ['Digital Marketing', 50],
            ['Research', 24],
            ['SEO', 11],
            ['Social Media Marketing', 59],
            ['Strategy', 43],
            ['UI', 22],
            ['UX', 73]
          ]
        };

        var zeroData = {
          rows: [
            ['Advertising', 0],
            ['Branding', 0],
            ['Creative Problem-Solving', 0],
            ['Digital Marketing', 0],
            ['Research', 0],
            ['SEO', 0],
            ['Social Media Marketing', 0],
            ['Strategy', 0],
            ['UI', 0],
            ['UX', 0]
          ]
        };

        var speed = 80; // speed in ms (smaller is faster)
        var step = 3; // adjust as needed

        // create a radar chart
        var chart = anychart.radar();

        // set the series type
        chart.defaultSeriesType('area');

        // set the color palette
        chart.palette(['#9BC53DE6']);

        // configure the appearance of the y-axis
        chart.yAxis().stroke('#000000');
        chart.yAxis().ticks().stroke('#000000');

        // configure the stroke of the x-grid
        chart.xGrid().stroke({
          color: "#545f69",
          thickness: 0.5,
          dash: "10 5"
        });

        // configure the appearance of the y-grid
        chart.yGrid().palette(['gray 0.05', 'gray 0.025']);

        // begin the y-scale at 0
        chart.yScale().minimum(0);

        // set the y-scale ticks interval
        chart.yScale().ticks().interval(10);

        // set the hover mode
        chart.interactivity().hoverMode('by-x');

        //  set the marker type
        chart.markerPalette(['star5']);

        // improve the tooltip
        chart.tooltip()
          .displayMode('union')
          .useHtml(true)
          .format(function(e){
            console.log(this);
            return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color() + '">' +
              this.seriesName + ": " + this.value + "</span>"
          });

        // set chart legend settings
        chart.legend()
          .align('center')
          .position('center-bottom')
          .enabled(false);

        // set the chart title
        chart.title("Services");

        // set container id for the chart
        chart.container('container');

        // initiate chart drawing
        chart.draw();

        function animateChart(fromData, toData) {
          var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fromData)); 
          var index = 0;
          var expandingInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (index < data.rows.length) {
              var targetValue = toData.rows[index][1];
              if (data.rows[index][1] < targetValue) {
                data.rows[index][1] += step;
                chart.data(data);
                chart.draw();
              } else {
                index++;
              }
            } else {
              clearInterval(expandingInterval);
              var collapsingIndex = data.rows.length - 1;
              var collapsingInterval = setInterval(function() {
                if (collapsingIndex >= 0) {
                  data.rows[collapsingIndex][1] -= step;
                  chart.data(data);
                  chart.draw();
                  if (data.rows[collapsingIndex][1] <= 0) {
                    data.rows[collapsingIndex][1] = 0; 
                    collapsingIndex--;
                    if (collapsingIndex < 0) {
                      clearInterval(collapsingInterval);
                      animateChart(zeroData, originalData); 
                    }
                  }
                }
              }, speed);
            }
          }, speed);
        }

        animateChart(zeroData, originalData);

      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>




Hello. Thank you so much this is perfect and exactly what I am looking for.  I really appreciate all the help. Thank you!
